# 802.11N in TP-LINK TL-WN722N

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, dongle, hostapd

I'm using usb dongle TL-WN722N as Acess Point on my Raspberry Pi B 2. It works as AP but I can't get 802.11N speeds to work. My max Bit Rates is 65 Mb/s. Is this correct?

**sudo iw list:**

```
Wiphy phy0
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x116e
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
        max # scan SSIDs: 4
        max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
                * 00-0f-ac:10
                * 00-0f-ac:8
                * 00-0f-ac:9
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
                * 00-0f-ac:13
                * 00-0f-ac:11
                * 00-0f-ac:12
        Available Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x1
        Configured Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x1
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
                 * mesh point
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
        software interface modes (can always be added):
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed, P2P-client } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-GO } <= 2,
                   total <= 2, #channels <= 1
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * new_beacon
                 * new_station
                 * new_mpath
                 * set_mesh_params
                 * set_bss
                 * authenticate
                 * associate
                 * deauthenticate
                 * disassociate
                 * join_ibss
                 * join_mesh
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * set_tx_bitrate_mask
                 * action
                 * frame_wait_cancel
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * set_wds_peer
                 * Unknown command (82)
                 * Unknown command (81)
                 * Unknown command (84)
                 * Unknown command (87)
                 * Unknown command (85)
                 * Unknown command (89)
                 * Unknown command (92)
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.
        HT Capability overrides:
                 * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
                 * maximum A-MSDU length
                 * supported channel width
                 * short GI for 40 MHz
                 * max A-MPDU length exponent
                 * min MPDU start spacing
        Device supports TX status socket option.
        Device supports HT-IBSS.
```

**sudo iwconfig:**

```
mon.wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**scan:**

```
  Cell 03 - Address: ***
            ESSID:"***"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:65 Mb/s
            Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Quality=48/100  Signal level=76/100  
            Extra:fm=0003
```